# Complex Concatenation Of Two Headings

Tags: c#, string

If I have the following headings in a .txt file:

```
     CUSTOMER             PAYMENT       ERR CORR    PAYMENT AMOUNT     PAYMENT  
  REFERENCE NUMBER    INSTRUCTION TYPE   REASON*                        TYPE**
```

How can I create a `List<string>` with the following elements:

`CUSTOMER REFERENCE NUMBER`, `PAYMENT INSTRUCTION TYPE`, `ERR CORR REASON*`,   `PAYMENT AMOUNT`, `PAYMENT TYPE**`

Another example:

```
     CUSTOMER             PAYMENT       ERR CORR    PAYMENT AMOUNT     PAYMENT  
  REFERENCE NUMBER    INSTRUCTION TYPE                                  TYPE**
```

would give me:
 `CUSTOMER REFERENCE NUMBER`, `PAYMENT INSTRUCTION TYPE`, `ERR CORR`,   `PAYMENT AMOUNT`, `PAYMENT TYPE**`

Note that headings are spaced by a number of white spaces >= 2 while each word in the one heading is separated by one white space. It's possible to have headings written only on the first row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way. First, "merge" the two lines together. I am assuming they are the same length. Example:

```
var s1 = "    CUSTOMER             PAYMENT       ERR CORR    PAYMENT AMOUNT     PAYMENT  ";
var s2 = " REFERENCE NUMBER    INSTRUCTION TYPE   REASON*                        TYPE**  ";

var merged = new string(Enumerable.Range(0, s1.Length)
    .Select(t=>s1[t]!=' ' ? s1[t] : s2[t]).ToArray());
```

This gets you something like:

```
 REFCUSTOMERUMBER    INSTPAYMENT TYPE  ERRACORR    PAYMENT AMOUNT     PAYMENT
```

Then, look for the indexes of double (or more) spaces in that string:

```
var indexes = Regex.Matches(merged, @"  +").OfType<Match>().Select(t=>t.Index).ToList();
```

Then, use those indexes to cut both strings up and concatenate them, trimming off the whitespace.   I explicitly add the start and end of the string, in case there is no double whitespace on the ends.

```
indexes.Insert(0, 0);
indexes.Add(merged.Length-1);

indexes.Sort(); // not sure if Regex.Matches will necessarily be in order

var columns = new List<string>();
for (int i=0; i<indexes.Count-1;i++) 
{
    var column = (
        s1.Substring(indexes[i], indexes[i+1]-indexes[i]).Trim() + " " + 
        s2.Substring(indexes[i], indexes[i+1]-indexes[i]).Trim()
        ).Trim();
    if (column != string.Empty) 
        columns.Add(column);
}
```

This gets you the output:

```
CUSTOMER REFERENCE NUMBER 
PAYMENT INSTRUCTION TYPE 
ERR CORR REASON* 
PAYMENT AMOUNT 
PAYMENT TYPE**
```

And [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jsYGcM) is a working example.

Comment: I finally got around to using this solution.
Absolutely elegant, my solution involved many more lines of code, so glad to be able to use this one, thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

If the txt's format just like you said,here is a demo

```
string[] arr = {
                            @" CUSTOMER             PAYMENT       ERR CORR    PAYMENT AMOUNT     PAYMENT  
REFERENCE NUMBER    INSTRUCTION TYPE   REASON*                        TYPE**",
                                                                            @"      CUSTOMER             PAYMENT       ERR CORR    PAYMENT AMOUNT     PAYMENT  
REFERENCE NUMBER    INSTRUCTION TYPE                                  TYPE**"
                        };
foreach (string str in arr)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    var tmp = Regex.Split(str.Trim(), @"\s{2,}");
    list.Add(tmp[0] + " " + tmp[5]);
    list.Add(tmp[1] + " " + tmp[6]);
    if (tmp.Length == 9)
    {
        list.Add(tmp[2] + " " + tmp[7]);
    }
    else
    {
        list.Add(tmp[2]);
    }
    list.Add(tmp[3]);
    list.Add(tmp[4] + " " + tmp[tmp.Length - 1]);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", list));
}
```

Comment: there're hard coded numbers in there. Would this work if headings were added or modified?